# getImeiForSlot: The user 10170 does not meet the requirements to access device identifiers

Tags: java, android, imei

I have **android 10** I want to get **IMEI** below is my manifest settings

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

and below is my java code to get the IMEI but I am getting the above error.

```
        Button btnAuth = findViewById(R.id.button);
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        btnAuth.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    Log.i("huwa ", telephonyManager.getImei());
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.i("huwa ", e.toString());
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't get READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE.  It's only available to privleged system apps.  Unless this is a personal app and you have a rooted device so you can make your app a privleged system app.

Answer (score -2):

As Mentioned in Docs , There is a Restriction on non-resettable device identifiers.

Starting in Android 10, apps must have the READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE privileged permission in order to access the device's non-resettable identifiers, which include both IMEI and serial number.

> Caution: Third-party apps installed from the Google Play Store cannot
> declare privileged permissions.

Ref : https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#non-resettable-device-ids